# Can you put a matte polyurethane over a semi-gloss polyurethane to make it a matte finish?

Tags: furniture, polyurethane, varnishing

I have a piece of furniture that my mom has painted and she put on a semi-gloss polyurethane finish.  It is way too shiny for the type of painting.

Can we put a matte polyurethane finish over the semi-gloss one to make it more of a matte or satin finish?

Answer (score 3):

Yes (with some prep), however, you can try lightly sanding with 600 grit wet/dry sandpaper.  Use it lightly wetted. Buff dry with a soft cloth.  You may find this is matte enough.. DONE!

If its too matte (flat) you are now prepped and ready to recoat with satin or matte.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I just put matte poly over satin poly on baseboards and it toned the shine down dramatically. It was an easy solution. I did not sand or prep. Worked fine.